# How to let ar_track_alvar only detect certain tags

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

So, I'm running ar_track_alvar (the groovy branch) to detect ar tags. It all went well except sometimes it detects something that's not a tag as a tag 154 or some other tag that is way off from like that, So I'm wondering if there is some way I can do to let it only detects the tag that I want it to detect?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198983/how-to-let-ar_track_alvar-only-detect-certain-tags/) by [yicheng0922](https://answers.ros.org/users/21038/yicheng0922/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest that you just filter the tags after it detects them and republish the filtered set removing any detections that are known out of the scope of the expected tags.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1